# how to identify user who created a specific job on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jobs

**Problem**

In jenkins, I cannot find the job creator for a specific task.

**Tries**

I tried looking in the changes log, do not display creation. Looked up in the user profiles and there is no such properties. Been fooling aroung for a while now trying to find it. Also most research on google with keyword "creator" will fetch results about how to create a job or other questions of people who searched things relative to this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [JobConfigHistory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) is ought to display a column *User.* And so does it in my Jenkins (v1.609.1) when I select a job's *Job Config History* at the bottom of the sidebar menu immediately after creating a job.

(Though I agree: There's no *Created* there, just *Changed.* But, changing from non-existence to existence is a *change*, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: you're right! The thing is I was looking for the latest change, and it's not the latest one (weird)
now I see it, thanks a lot

Comment: If I don't have the JobConfigHistory plugin, is there anywhere else I can look for this information? (I presume installing the plugin now won't help retroactively.)

Comment: @dpercy I'm not aware of any place where this info should be kept. You could check the creation time of the job's `config.xml` and the (http) logs of your OS to see which user/s was/were logged on at that time, to limit the number of candidates, at least.